# Is there an audio converter frontend that can handle tags and uses ffmpeg as backend?

Tags: software-recommendation, ffmpeg

I am especially interested in possibility to use a custom build of ffmpeg and use exactly the encoder I want; something like soundconverter otherwise.

Comment: Why not just use ffmpeg?

Comment: @llogan I want an easy way to encode tree of stuff with metadata (e.g. song names) included.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)

Comment: @llogan the answer you linked does not show how to copy metadata. Apparently that is possible by complex `-map_metadata` option, though.

Comment: ffmpeg copies metadata by default.

Comment: @llogan Good to know